# How to install Cloudera Hadoop in a PC which does not support virtualization

Tags: hadoop, virtualization, cloudera-quickstart-vm

i like to install Cloudera Hadoop in my computer windows 7.so i download a vmware player but it doesn't work because my computer doesn't support virtualisation.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't boot a virtual machine, then you're out of luck.

But yes, there are 2 solutions: get a new computer that supports virtualization (with at least 8 Gb RAM because that's what you need to run the VM) or install Cloudera Manager on a bare metal server.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer doesn't support virtualization you can't run Cloudera VM. Check below requirements to run Cloudera VM

1. These 64-bit VMs require a 64-bit host OS and a virtualization product that can support a 64-bit guest OS.
2. To use a VMware VM, you must use a player compatible with WorkStation 8.x or higher:
       Player 4.x or higher
       Fusion 4.x or higher

   Older versions of WorkStation can be used to create a new VM using the same virtual disk (VMDK file), but some features in VMware Tools are not available.

The amount of RAM required varies by the run-time option you choose:

```
CDH and Cloudera Manager Version    RAM Required by VM
CDH 5 (default)                      4+ GiB*
Cloudera Express                     8+ GiB*
Cloudera Enterprise (trial)          10+ GiB*

*Minimum recommended memory. If you are running workloads larger than the examples provided, consider allocating additional memory.
```

`http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-4.html`